# What is the difference between network sparsification and model pruning

Tags: neural-networks, sparse, pruning

What is the difference between network sparsification and model pruning? I watched [USENIX ATC '21 - Octo: INT8 Training with Loss-aware Compensation and Backward Quantization for Tiny](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TG3BO8muC4w&ab_channel=USENIX) (at 01:29sec) where they state them as two different methods to simplify the model.

I have difficulties understanding what is the difference.

Answer (score 1):

There is no operational difference. A pruned network is usually leads to a sparser network. However, the degree of sparsification, i.e., how much it is pruned, would determine if it is qualified as "sparse network". One could think of difference between a dense matrix and a [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix), from weight matrices perspective. Probably, rule of thumb is maybe if 90% or more connections are pruned, it is a sparse network compare to the original one, see [The Lottery Ticket Hypothesis: Finding Sparse, Trainable Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.03635).

Comment: So they are not two different things but related. Two of them is about having more zero weights in the weight matrix or removing a weight matrix completely can also be a solution to the sparse matrix?

Comment: Yes, they are related. The idea is much more zeros in the weight matrix (recall connectivity matrix), i.e., removed connections means a sparse network. In implementations usually we don't assign zero weight but remove the corresponding connection completely.

Comment: is this also feasible considering cnn types of networks? removing connection completely instead of assigning zero weights?

Comment: Yes. CNN size will be smaller. Extended discussions in comments are discouraged. Please don't continue asking new questions in comments.